# Could not cast value of type

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am creating a Tic Tac Toe app. When the game resets, all the Xs and Os `UIButton` images should return to `nil`. Each space in the board is tagged from 0 to 8.

```
  var buttonsToClear : UIButton

    for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {

        buttonsToClear = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

        buttonsToClear.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)

    }
```

Everything worked fine until I added a Navigation Bar. Now I get the error message

> "Could not cast value of type '_UINavigationBarBackground' (0x107e2f2a0) >to 'UIButton' (0x107e357e0).
>   (lldb)

I am absolutely certain that my new Navigation Bar has a tag of "10".

[image: Navigation Bar Tag]

What else could be triggering this message?

Comment: it's not the navigation bar itself that's causing the crash, it's the bar background, which is a private property of `UINavigationBar`

Comment: Try printing `print("i = \(i): \(view.viewWithTag(i)?.description ?? "")")` in the top of your loop, just to see for what tag value and for what view object that your `viewWithTag` apparently returns a non-button view. Also, possibly set tag values for UIButtons and your nav bar programatically in you `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Also, consider conditional unwrapping: `if let buttonsToClear = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton { .... }`,  and set the image only if it's a button. It is a good practice, much safer, and should you change your tags, you'll never attempt to setImage to something rather than a button.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use 0 tag, due to 0 is default and you can get any view (in this case the background of the navigation).

Tag the views starting by 1.

Answer (score 4):

**You are logically right and your code will work perfectly.**

You are getting the error

> "Could not cast value of type '_UINavigationBarBackground'
>   (0x107e2f2a0) >to 'UIButton' (0x107e357e0). (lldb)

Because, when your `for loop` runs, the first index will be zero i.e. i = 0,

```
buttonsToClear = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
```

will become

```
buttonsToClear = view.viewWithTag(0) as! UIButton
```

So in this case you are trying to get the view with `tag` value 0.

`UINavigationBarBackground` also has tag value 0.

**Note:**

**1. when system finds two view with same tag value, and you are trying to get view using `viewWithTag:` it will return first view.**

**2. Every View Has default tag value 0.**

**3. Just drag UILabel or UIView in storyboard or XIB and check its tag value.**

So in your case it will return `UINavigationBarBackground` instead of `UIButton`. So you can't type-cast `UINavigationBarBackground` into `UIButton`.

**Solution of your Error :**

Never give tags starting from 0. 
Try to give tags starting for some value like 1000.
so your first button will have tag 1000, next will have 1001, then 1002 and so-on.

write your for loop as below.

```
var buttonsToClear : UIButton

    for var i = 1000; i < 1009; i++ {

        buttonsToClear = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

        buttonsToClear.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)

    }
```

Comment: I still wouldn't force cast the `UIView` to a `UIButton` by using `as!`, I would use `as?` to check the type first.

Answer (score 1):

You must be able to see the stack trace to see where this is being triggered? In any case, the obvious solution is to run this in the debugger, turn on exception breakpoints and see what's going on.

And as Jose says, don't use Tag 0.

Answer (score 0):

### You need a new approach that doesn't rely on *only* using tags to identify your subviews

---

The problem is, your loop is coming across a private property on `UINavigationBar`, `_UINavigationBarBackground`. Because you can't set the tag on this, it will have the default tag of `0`. Therefore you will attempt to send a `UIButton` function to it.

I would simply loop through your subviews and check if a view is of type `UIButton`, and *then* check it's tags (be sure still not to use tag `0`, as that is the default tag) before removing it. **That way you are 100% sure that you've gotten the right subview.**

```
var buttonsToClear : UIButton

for view in view.subviews { // Loop through subviews
    if let button = view as? UIButton { // Check if UIButton
        if button.tag > 0 || button.tag < 10 { // Check tags
            buttonsToClear = button
            buttonsToClear.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```